# Is there a way to make line wrap following indentation no matter which langage it is opening?

Tags: eclipse

I am writing PHP + Javascript for web development. Previously I have used a few different editor, namely notepad++, sublime and Atom. And recently I am giving IDE a try and choose Eclipse.

To my surprise, the line wrap in Eclipse is not following indentation by default (even Notepad++ line wrap is following indentation, even when editing plain text!). I have done a bit Google, but the solution doesn't work (as the solution seems to be a bit old. Most of them in 2010-2014). And even if it works, all the solution seems language specific. Is there a way to set Eclipse so that the line wrap will follow indentation by default, no matter which programming language I am working on?

P.S. as someone is asking for explanation in comment, I think a few image will help.
This is the behavior of line wrap in eclipse
[image]

I would expect something like this (from notepad++):
[image]
Or this (from Atom)
[image]

Comment: @greg-449 Updated post to explain what is "line wrap following indentation"

Comment: I can't even find where to activate line wrap (never though about using it for code)... Okay, found it: Window -> Editor -> Toggle Word Wrap.

Comment: Or alt-shift-Y for hotkey..... I must say I am surprised that someone writing code never think of using word wrap. (well, not a must to use, but like tab or space debate, this option should have stayed in your mind for some time)

Comment: Guess it depends on the language; for HTML and other markup it's certainly useful, but in "proper" programming languages I try to keep my lines short or wrap manually if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible (I know this because I reviewed and improved the code of the initial implementation four years ago).

See [Eclipse bug 35779](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=35779) which contains links to the implementation (Git commits) at the top right in the *See Also* section.

You could [report this as a feature request to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=Text&bug_severity=enhancement) with an explanation of how it should behave with larger indents (the idea of the word wrap mode is to use the space as much as possible, while an indentation wastes space).

Comment: It is really disappointing that Eclipse is not providing such basic function, but at least this answer confirm us that we can stop searching. Bounty rewarded for cutting the pain short.